# How to pronounce English /w/?

Tags: pronunciation

> “Indonesia has likened Australia's spying efforts to a Cold War tactic and says it ***would*** like an explanation within a couple of days. ([ABC.net.au](http://www.abc.net.au/am/content/2013/s3893831.htm))”

It’s not easy for me to catch the /w/ sound in general. And I wonder if ***would*** in [the audio](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/422) was pronounced with /w/ (strong form, CGEL p1613) or not (weak form). I’d like some tips on how to pronounce the sound and catch it. (Even though I myself tried with [BBC Learning English](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/pron/sounds/) and so forth, it’s like sailing through without foghorn on dimly lit routes.)

Comment: @Wendikidd, Thank you the word, lit. Without it, it was strange myself. But I didn't know how to or what to do in the part.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to help :)

Comment: Listenever, this may help you http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/would_1?q=would#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of possibilities for /w/ in English. I'm not sure if you're referring to orthography specifically or linguistics in general, so I'll briefly give you a few examples of each.

The strong form would be the /w/ in *would, wood, bowl, etc.*

The weaker form is /hw/, with a barely audible (if at all) /h/. It's a softer sound found in words like *who, what, why, etc.*

It depends on the speaker's dialect, but sometimes this difference can be heard in words like *welp/whelp*, but not all speakers exhibit this.

And on the off chance that you're strictly asking about orthography, as a vowel, *w* is like the *u* in the words *duo, and bough*, or the *w* in cow*. In this use, it's similar to the Greek letter Omega. (Also heard at the end of the words *do* and *dew*)

Comment: The words *do* and *dew* are not always pronounced the same. That depends on dialect.

Comment: @Tristan Yes you are correct; I was referencing General American. It's impossible to answer questions on phonology universally because of the wide range of dialects.

Comment: That's a good point, John.

Comment: In nearly all dialects of English, *which* is pronounced exactly the same way as *witch* today. That's not the *weak form* the OP is talking about.